# Interpretation of error bars with covariance

Tags: interpretation

I am working on decision making under uncertainty, in which I have four technologies which I should compare them in terms of some decision criteria. These decision criteria are evaluated as probability distribution functions from which I extract two values including modal value and confidence interval values for each technology (min/modal/max).

At the end for each criterion I would have an error bar for each technology that I should interpret them. However I have faced a problem regarding interpretation of these error bars. Since the uncertain parameters are changing from one technology into another, I can not claim that all minimum values on these error bars would happen at the same time, and all maximum values would happen at the same time. There is possibility that minimum value of one technology happens when the maximum value of another is happening. As I understood it means that I have covariance.

I do greatly appreciate if you can let me know if there is any technique for interpreting these error bars when we do have covariance.

Thank you very much in advance for giving your time to help me.

Best regards
Shabnam

Comment: I don't completely follow your situation. Can you provide an example? Is this something like a person can choose 1 from {A, B}, & chooses 1 from {C, D}, where you have probabilities for each choice individually, but you think people may be more likely to choose C if they just chose A?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. As an example I have four technologies A,B,C,D among which I am should select the best using a decision criterion R. At the end I have R as probability distribution functions which I extract its modal value and min and max values considering 95% confidence interval for each technology.

Comment: At the end I have R values for four technologies. However for example minimum possible R value in technology A happens because of increase in feed price, while the minimum possible R value for technology B happens when the cost of fuel increases. It means that all minimum values of the criterion is not because of the same reason and so we should not compare just the minimum values with each other and maximum values with each other, there can be a possibility to have minimum value of this criterion for technology A when we have the max for technology B (I am comparing the error bars).

Comment: This is the problem I have for interpreting the overlap in final error bars being able to identify the best technology option. I wish I could clarify it a little bit more. I appreciate if you help me in this way. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Notation:**

Let $R_A$ be the probability density function or even a random variable when technology A is used. In any case, $R_A,R_B,R_C,R_D$ can be thought of transformations of your inputs which are uncertain. Let $(x_A,x_B,x_C,x_D)$ be these uncertain inputs.

1. In one extreme, $x_A = x_B = x_C = x_D$. That is, all the inputs are the same. In this case, you can compare the modal/mean and confidence intervals as one way to judge the performance of these technologies.
2. In the more interesting case, these are not the same but you have some dependence information. One version of dependence can be described by correlation. This means that the quantities $R_A,R_B,R_C,R_D$ are also correlated. (*Note:* there could be higher order dependences as well.)

**Evaluation:**

Now let us discuss the evaluations when there is dependence (correlation) and contrast it with the independent case.

For this let us just consider two instead of four technologies to see how they can be evaluated. That is, consider only $R_A$ and $R_B$. Let them be correlated with coefficient $\rho$. Let them represent random variables with say, normal distributions (though this is not important).

1. In the independent case, plotting the 25th, 50th (mean) and the 75th quantile (*error bars*) makes sense as suggested in the question.
2. Do *error bars* make sense in the dependent case? 
   I contend that placing the error bars of $R_A$ and $R_B$ make sense. That is because, $R_A$ may be correlated with $R_B$ but nonetheless, we know the (marginal) distribution of $R_A$ and it contains all the information to assess this random quantity.

If the purpose on the other hand is to see how $R_A$ behaves in relation to $R_B$ we could do the following: fix is to look at the 2D plot of the joint distribution of $R_A,R_B$. They will give you a visual way to see how $R_A$ and $R_B$ are related. For instance, if $\rho$ is positive or negative, you will see tilted ellipsoids whereas when $\rho$ is zero, you will see circles.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and many thanks for your detailed explanation. As far as I know in a case that we don't have any dependency between the distributions, when we have overlap in error bars, significance test can help us to identify if two distributions are distinguishable or not. In the case of dependent distributions, I am not sure if ρ would play the kind of same role or not. I appreciate if you let me know more that after identifying ρ  what I can do being able to interpret the results of evaluated criteria under uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you very much in advance for giving your time to this.